# Can QGIS report/calculate areas/perimeters of individual polygon components within multipart shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, field-calculator, fields-attributes

Can QGIS report/calculate the areas/perimeters of individual polygon components within a multipart shapefile without using the "explode" vector tool to generate a new file?

using QGIS 2.2.0 on Windows from OSGEO4W

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Please note that I have edited your Question to include the title content as part of the body because the former is meant to summarise the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any ready-made functionality to do this. There are different options to get results like that:

1. write Python code: pyQGIS directly or through Processing
2. create a Processing model combining explode and calculate area into one tool - useful if you have to redo this operation multiple times
3. just accept it, and do explode and then calculate area manually

Comment: Thanks - I built a quick Processing model with a temporary output file that did the trick.  This brings up one additional question - am I correct in thinking that Processing cannot output to the same file that is its input? (i.e. InputShape -> Explode -> Add geometry -> OutputShape where InputShape=OutputShape)

Comment: I don't think there is an option to make Processing overwrite the input file.